# Getting status "Incomplete" on stripe always

Tags: android, kotlin, stripe-payments, payment, strip

I'm always getting `incomplete` at `onCompletePayment` and I'm also checked stripe sample app but it's also not working for me. I have check lot but I unable rectify the issue.

So what's would be error on my side?

**Source :**

```
PaymentConfiguration.init(BuildConfig.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY)
    /* Initialized customer*/

 private fun setupPaymentSession() {
    mPaymentSession = PaymentSession(mvpView?.baseActivity!!)

    val paymentSessionInitialized = mPaymentSession!!.init(object : PaymentSession.PaymentSessionListener {


override fun onCommunicatingStateChanged(isCommunicating: Boolean) {
            if (isCommunicating) {
            } else {
            }
        }

        override fun onError(errorCode: Int, errorMessage: String?) {
        }

        override fun onPaymentSessionDataChanged(data: PaymentSessionData) {
            mPaymentSessionData = data
            checkForCustomerUpdates()
        }
    }, PaymentSessionConfig.Builder()
            /* .setPrepopulatedShippingInfo(getExampleShippingInfo())
             .setHiddenShippingInfoFields(ShippingInfoWidget.PHONE_FIELD, ShippingInfoWidget.CITY_FIELD)*/
            .setShippingInfoRequired(false)
            .build())
    if (paymentSessionInitialized) {
        mPaymentSession?.setCartTotal(20L)
    }
}

    override fun handlePaymentData(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (data != null) {
        mPaymentSession?.handlePaymentData(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        mPaymentSession?.completePayment(PaymentCompletionProvider { paymentData, listener ->
            Toast.makeText(mvpView?.baseActivity!!, "success" + paymentData.paymentResult, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            listener.onPaymentResult(paymentData.paymentResult)
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not familiar with Kotlin but in the code snippet you provided, I'd suggest not to override `handlePaymentData`.

Instead call `mPaymentSession.handlePaymentData` in the `onActivityResult` of your host `Activity` like it is suggested in the doc [here](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android/standard#managing-paymentsession-in-a-host-activity) or as shown [in the example here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/blob/a1e88a0726ffdb598b26a829eb95227096e085ab/example/src/main/java/com/stripe/example/activity/PaymentSessionActivity.java#L173-L177) so that any updates to the `PaymentSessionData` is reported to your `PaymentSessionListener` that you attached when initializing `PaymentSession` (i.e with `mPaymentSession!!.init`).

Also generally, depending on your app Checkout flow, you would want to call `mPaymentSession.completePayment(...)` as a result of your user clicking for example on a "Pay" button.

You would pass to the `completePayment(...)` call a `PaymentCompletionProvider` which would:

1. send an HTTP request to your backend so that you can create a charge using Stripe's API
2. mark the result of the payment using `listener.onPaymentResult(...)` passing `PaymentResultListener.SUCCESS` in the case where the payment was for example successful.

I don't think that the example app has an example of this but in Java you could for example have a click listener on your "Pay" button setup like below:

```java
Button payButton = findViewById(R.id.pay_bttn);
payButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (mPaymentSessionData.isPaymentReadyToCharge() && mPaymentSessionData.getPaymentResult() == PaymentResultListener.SUCCESS) {
            // Use the data to complete your charge - see below.
            mPaymentSession.completePayment(new PaymentCompletionProvider() {
                @Override
                public void completePayment(@NonNull PaymentSessionData data, @NonNull PaymentResultListener listener) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Completing payment with data: " + data.toString());

                    // This is where you want to call your backend...
                    // In this case mark the payment as Successful
                    listener.onPaymentResult(PaymentResultListener.SUCCESS);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks and I overrided `onActivtyResult` and called `handlePaymentData()` in it. but it's not working

Comment: so we need api for stripe charge ? if it's getting success ,`completePayment` will call. am I right?

Comment: my understanding is that you call `mPaymentSession.completePayment` to complete the purchase (e.g when you the user click Pay) then yes, the `completePayment` method of your `PaymentCompletionProvider` is called. It is in this method that you send a HTTP request your backend (server side). Your backend should then call Stripe's Create Charge API method (https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) using the source that was selected by the user.

Comment: also I'd suggest to remove your override of  handlePaymentData as well.
If it's still not working I'd suggest to send an email to Stripe support for them to take a look: https://support.stripe.com/email